# Mysql query time to show result with default date time value

Tags: mysql

I have part of my mysql query as below

```
Select sNumber  From serial Where  
TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(  '2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime ) ) >=300
```

It works fine to generate a result if the time diff is in comparison to the lastEvenTime is more than 300 seconds. My issue now is that if the lastEventTime is the default value "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then it sends me as empty result. How to ensure that if its default value then I would like to show too as result?

Comment: Use a case to verify lastEventTime value

Comment: Do you mean run another separate query to compare its value is "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ?

Comment: If lastEventTime is on default value, what do you want your query to return?

Comment: I want the query to return as the same result as more than > 300 seconds which means that it did not find the lastEventTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select sNumber  From serial Where  
TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lastEventTime='0000-00-00 00:00:00',300,
TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime)) ) >=300
```

Please let me know if it helps you.

**EDIT**

If you change your field to null, try this:

```
Select sNumber  From serial Where  
TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lastEventTime IS NULL,300,
TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime)) ) >=300
```

**EDIT 2**

Try this one instead:

```
Select sNumber  From serial Where  
IF(lastEventTime IS NULL,300,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime))) >=300
```

Comment: No it does not give you as a result still

Comment: The comparation must not be working. What do you get when you run: Select sNumber, lastEventTime  From serial Where  
TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lastEventTime='0000-00-00 00:00:00',300,
TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime)) ) >=300

Comment: It just like previously empty results

Comment: Are you sure of the default value of lastEventTime? Isn't a null value instead? Try: Select sNumber,lastEventTime From serial (Without any WHERE)

Comment: please post some data from Serial Table (2 or 3 records)

Comment: Yes I have confirm that it give me the as e.g. BN21211,0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: what type of field is lastEventTime?

Comment: try this: Select sNumber  From serial Where  
TIME_TO_SEC(IF(lastEventTime<'2014-01-01',300,
TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime)) ) >=300

Comment: Its datetime   No default is  this0000-00-00 00:00:00 ? Should I change any other value as default to say there that column have not proper dateTime yet

Comment: Can't you make that field default value to null? that would help simplify your problem.

Comment: Yes I dont mind making it to null not a problem so what should I change no in the field to test? Should I remove the default 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I tried to make it default as null it gave me error then I check on the null checkbox and remove the value and gives me this error Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'lastEventTime' at row 1

Comment: Your column should allow null values, set the default value to null and edit you record to change '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to null

Comment: Ok I have done and check on the null and the value is now NULL. What query should I run I tried my original query still gives me empty result

Comment: I tried you second query also still the same no difference in the result at all it does not show the one will null value ?

Comment: I think the problem have to be related to time_to_sec function. Try my las update

Comment: How about me doing this TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-12-03 14:19:11', lastEventTime))) >=300 Or lastEventTime IS NULL ? Is this efficient ?